# How to save a Graph Data Structure to file? For example, a Function Call Graph of a software

Tags: data-structures, graph, graph-databases, call-graph

I am working on how to represent the Function Call Graph of a software and save the data structure into file. I know in memory the graph can be in the form of adjacency list or orthogonal list. My question is how to save the data structure into file, thus later on it can be reloaded into memory for further operations. Can it be represented in json, or by Graph Database such as Neo4j? What's more, if dumped into Neo4j, is it possible to calculate function call similarity?

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be represented in json, or by Graph Database such as Neo4j?

Both is ok.
You can use json to represent graphs ,such as [GraphSON](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/wiki/GraphSON-Format),[JSON Graph](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/jsongraph.html),etc.
Loading them into a graph database such as Neo4j is possible too.

> What's more, if dumped into Neo4j, is it possible to calculate function call similarity?

I'm not familiar with function call similarity, but there are some algorithms about similarity in Neo4j's graph algorithm package(https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/similarity/) that you can have a look to.

However, if all your computation is done in memory which means you read the data on the disk only one time and you choose to do the computation by yourself, directly dumping your memory graph data structure to disk maybe a better idea which is easy to implement and may give you better performance of loading data.

The format of graph storage highly depends on the form of graph computation so it will be a good help for my answering if you can provide some information about calculating function call similarity.

Comment: Thank you for you advice.  As for function call similarity, you can refer to a book named "malware analysis and detection" by Wang Junfeng et al.  There are also some papers on this topic, "Detecting malware variants via function-call graph similarity", "A similarity metric method of obfuscated malware using function-call graph".